# нужно ли ставить мягкий знак (после буквы Т) в слове - перенасытится

Tags: орфография

Фраза полностью звучит вот так:
***Думаю довольно быстро рынок перенасытится и цены придут в норму.***

1. С одной стороны есть правила написания глаголов, -тся/-ться.
   По данному правилу без мягкого знака.
2. Но есть словари, где указано данное слово с мягким знаком.

Comment: А как насчёт слова «придут»? Те же сомнения?

Comment: не было вопроса. Но согласен по данной фразе получить полный разбор

Comment: Рынок "что  сделает?" - Перенасытится.
Рынку нужно "что сделать?" - Перенасытиться

Answer (score 3):

В словаре вы могли видеть **Ь** только у *неопределённой формы* глагола, которая *всегда* отвечает на вопрос "что делат**Ь**"? Ставьте этот вопрос в неясных случаях, тогда не ошибётесь - **Ь** как бы переходит из этого вопроса в ответ. А в вашем примере - вопрос *без* этого самого знака: *что сделае**Т***?